# Sapply processing extra duplicate block of data

Tags: r, sapply

I have built a model in R that I am trying to test using `sapply()` (I know this may seem strange -- it's due to the peculiarities of how the model will be deployed). However, in working on that function, I have stumbled on a strange, problematic behavior of `sapply()`. Here is the code:

```
sapply(1:nrow(test_x), function(i) {
  print(i)
  print(test_x[i,]$Age)
  # actual functionality here... 
  }
)
```

At first, the output is normal, and then at the end it re-prints the entire column on a single line:

```
[1] 1
[1] 71
[1] 2
[1] 71
[1] 3
[1] 55
...
[1] 5506
[1] 37
[1] 5507
[1] 65
[1] 71 71 55 62 61 68 69 62 62 52 43 52 57 42 41 48 53 60 38
[20] 56 58 63 68 46 60 43 60 52 54 56 41 41 40 55 70 61 64 42 ...
```

And so on. Has anyone encountered this? I'm pretty new to R and to the `apply()` functions especially. I'm sure there's a better way to do what I'm doing but for now I'm just looking to get to the bottom of this bug.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`sapply` returns values; that's the whole point of the function. You print things inside the loop, and at the end the R console will print the return value of the whole `sapply`, which is a list (or vector) of the results of the individual applications of the function. Store the output in a variable if you want to reuse it.

If you only need to print and not do anything with the variables, you can just use a `for` loop instead of an apply function.

Answer (score 0):

`print` returns the value it printed (at least for atomic vectors). As the 2nd `print` call is the last command in the function, `print`'s return value is used as the function's return value. So for each call of `i`, `sapply` is collecting `test_x[i,]$Age`, and returning it to you. As you are executing it interactively (I'm assuming), it gets printed.

For the latter, every time in the console you hit enter, if the result is not directed into a variable, it secretly gets sent to `print`:

```
> length(letters)
[1] 26
> print(length(letters))
[1] 26
```

To reiterate, the output from `sapply` is printed to screen. That's why you are seeing it a second time.